# Set checkbox in simple_list_item_checked from Cursor

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am beginner in Android developing.

I have a ListView of type android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked and I am trying to set the checkbox to value, which is in my Cursor under name "CHECKED". The problem is that I cannot find the id of the checkbox (I have tried android.R.id.checkbox, but it hasn't worked) and I don't know, how to set it based on my Cursor. The cursor is created from SQLite database table, where the "CHECKED" column is BOOLEAN type.

My code, which is not working:

```
lv.setAdapter(
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, mCursor,
                        new String[]{"NOTES", "CHECKED"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.checkbox}, 0));
```

Could you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you look inside `R.layout.simple_list_item_checked` xml file you will see that the checkbox id is `@android:id/text1`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `SimpleCursorAdapter` will **not** suffice for the task you want.

If you look inside into its `public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)` method (this is where the magic happens and your views are attached to the data you want to see) you can verify how the `SimpleCursorAdapter` does this, and in its logic there is no use case for binding a `CheckedTextView`

You can see for yourself here in [Google's code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29):

```
if (v instanceof TextView) {
   setViewText((TextView) v, text);
} 
else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
          setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
     } 
else {
       throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                                " view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter");
                    }
```

The only reason you are not getting the IllegalStateException is because [CheckedTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html) extends TextView.